# Close a bookmarklet after submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bookmarklet

This is related to question "[Bookmarklet behind elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360618/bookmarklet-behind-elements)".

I want to either self close the iframe after form submission or if not possible, add a close button with the iframe to close it. my bookmarklet at the moment is

```
javascript:(function(){var iFrame=document.createElement('IFRAME');iFrame.src='http://www.yeongbing.com/testform/dd-formmailer/dd-formmailer.php';iFrame.style.cssText='display:block;position:absolute;top:5%;left:60%;width:40%;height:51%;overflow:hidden;';document.body.insertBefore(iFrame,document.body.firstChild);})();
```

I have tried the methods mentioned [here](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=582469) but can't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can close the iframe from your "Close Window" button.

First, give your iframe an id by adding "iFrame.id='foo';" to the end of your bookmarklet script:

```
javascript:(function(){var iFrame=document.createElement('IFRAME');iFrame.src='test2.html';iFrame.style.cssText='display:block;position:absolute;top:5%;left:60%;width:40%;height:51%;overflow:hidden;';document.body.insertBefore(iFrame,document.body.firstChild);iFrame.id='foo';})();
```

Then, in your iframe's source, change

```
<input type="button" onclick=window.close() value="Close Window"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="parent.document.body.removeChild(parent.document.getElementById('foo'));" value="Close Window"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But the button neither work on the page itself nor the iframe. Do you know why onclick=window.close() by itself doesn't work? I thought it should close the window no matter what is within the webpage.

Comment: I tested my solution and it works. The button is in the iframe page itself, just as you already have on http://www.yeongbing.com/testform/dd-formmailer/dd-formmailer.php.

Comment: very weird. I try it in Safari and firefox and it does not work in both of them. I will check to see if i copied it wrongly. Thanks